# Writing access to private objects via public readOnly property

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation, readonly

I am currently struggling to understand something i just saw somewhere.

Lets say I have two classes :

```
 class MyFirstCLass{
      public int membVar1;
      private int membVar2;
      public string membVar3;
      private string membVar4; 

      public MyFirstClass(){
      }
 }
```

and :

```
 class MySecondClass{
      private MyFirstClass firstClassObject = new MyFirstClass();

      public MyFirstClass FirstClassObject{
           get{
                return firstClassObject;
           }
      }
 }
```

If i do something like this :

```
 var secondClassObject = new MySecondClass(){
      FirstClassObject = {membVar1 = 42, membVar3 = "foo"}
 };
```

secondClass is an instanciation of MySecondClass, and does have one private member variable of type MyFirstClass wich has a readOnly property. However, i am able to change the state of membVar1 and membVar2. Isn't there any encapsulation problem ?

Best regards,

Al_th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the FirstClassObject property on MySecondClass has no setter does not mean that the object returned from the getter becomes immutable. Since it has public fields, these fields are mutable. Therefore it is perfectly legal to say `secondClassObject.FirstClassObject.membVar1 = 42`. The absence of the setter only means that you cannot replace the object reference stored in the firstClassObject field with a reference to a different object.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: You are *not* changing the value of `MySecondClass.FirstClassObject`. You are simply changing the values inside that property.

Compare the following two snippets. The first is legal, the second is not as it tries to assign a new value to the `FirstClassObject` property:

```
// legal:
var secondClassObject = new MySecondClass(){ 
  FirstClassObject = {membVar1 = 42, membVar3 = "foo"} }

// won't compile:
// Property or indexer 'FirstClassObject' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
var secondClassObject = new MySecondClass(){ 
  FirstClassObject = new MyFirstClass {membVar1 = 42, membVar3 = "foo"} }
```

Basically, your code is just a very fancy way of writing this:

```
var secondClassObject = new MySecondClass();
secondClassObject.FirstClassObject.membVar1 = 42;
secondClassObject.FirstClassObject.membVar3 = "foo";
```

And that's how I would write it. It is explicit and understandable.

Comment: Upvoted because it did also enlight the answer of jonas. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither a storage location of type `MyFirstCLass`, nor the value returned by a a property of type `MyFirstCLass`, contains fields `membVar1`, `membVar2`, etc.  The storage location or property instead contains information sufficient to either *identify* an instance of `MyFirstCLass` or indicate that it is "null".  In some languages or frameworks, there exist reference types which identify an object but only allow certain operations to be performed on it, but Java and .NET both use Promiscuous Object References: if an object allows outside code that holds a reference to do something with it, any outside code that gets a reference will be able to do that.

If a class is using a mutable object to encapsulate its own state, and wishes to allow the outside world to see that state but not allow the outside world to tamper with it, it must not return the object directly to the outside code but instead give the outside code something else.  Possibilities include:

- Expose all the aspects of state encompassed by the object individually (e.g. have a `membVar1` property which returns the value of the encapsulated object's `membVar1`).  This can avoid confusion, but provides a caller with no way to handle the properties as a group.
- Return a new instance of a read-only wrapper which holds a reference to the private object, and has members that forward read requests (but not write requests) to those members.  The returned object will serve as a read-only "view", but outside code will have no nice way to identify whether two such objects are views of the same underlying object.
- Have a field of a read-only-wrapper type which is initialized in the constructor, and have a property return that.  If each object will only have one read-only wrapper associated with it, two wrapper references will view the same wrapped object only if they identify the same wrapper.
- Create an immutable copy of the underlying data, perhaps by creating a new mutable copy and returning a new read-only wrapper to it.  This will give the caller a "snapshot" of the data, rather than a live "view".
- Create a new mutable copy of the underlying data, and return that.  This has the disadvantage that a caller who tries to change the underlying data by changing the copy will be allowed to change the copy without any warnings, but the operation won't work.  All of the arguments for why mutable structs are "evil" apply doubly here: code which receives an exposed-field structure should *expect* that changes to the received structure won't affect the source from which it came, but code which receives a mutable class object has no way of knowing that.  Properties should not behave this way; such behavior is generally only appropriate for methods which make clear their intention (e.g. `FirstClassObjectAsNewMyFirstClass();`
- Require that the caller pass in a mutable object of a type that can accept the underlying data, and copy the data into that.  This gives the caller the data in a mutable form (which in some cases may be easier to work with) but at the same time avoids any confusion about who "owns" the object.  As an added bonus, if the caller will be making many queries, the caller may reuse the same mutable object for all of them, thus avoiding unnecessary object allocations.
- Encapsulate the data within a structure, and have a property return the structure.  Some people may balk at such usage, but it's a useful convention in cases where a caller may want to piecewise-modify the data.  This approach only really works if the data in question is limited to a fixed set of discrete values (such as the coordinates and dimensions of a rectangle), but has the advantage that if the caller understands what a .NET structure is (*as all .NET programmers should*) the semantics are inherently obvious.

Of these choices, only the last two make clear via the type system what semantics the caller should expect.  Accepting a mutable object from the caller offers clear semantics, but makes usage awkward.  Returning an exposed-field structure offers clear semantics but only if the data consists of a fixed set of discrete values. Returning a mutable copy of the data is sometimes useful, but is only appropriate if the method name makes clear what it is doing.  The other choices generally leave ambiguous the question of whether the data represents a snapshot or a live "view".